# How to add corresponding value into right column (I have a code but its not fast enough)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a 'test excel' to test my macro.
In my test excel, I have columns from A to F. I have to add a value to column F IF column A has a same value as column G has. Also I need to delete all the possible duplicates from the range from A to C. Here is an example:

```
 A  B  C  D  E  F      G  H
 1  2  2  2  2         1  work
 2  3  3  3  3         2  school
 2  3  3  3  3
 4  1  1  1  1

 After macro ----->

   One
A  B  C  D  E  F         G  H
1  2  2  2  2  work      1  work
2  3  3  3  3  school    2  school
4  1  1  1  1
```

So now, the list has been updated with values on Column F and deleted third row (because it was a duplicate).

This is what I have tried already. I dont know, how to do that macro checks column G and adds a columns H value to column F if the values are the same. Here is what I have done:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3),     Header:=xlYes

For Each ordernmb In Range("A1:A100")
    If ordernmb = "1" Then
        ordernmb.Offset(0, 5).Value = "work"

    ElseIf ordernmb = "2" Then
        ordernmb.Offset(0, 5).Value = "school"

    End If

    Next ordernmb

End Sub
```

In the real excel, I have over 10 000 rows, 15 columns so this code was way to slow for that. What should I do?

Comment: This looks very much like a `LOOKUP` table. So the most simple solution in your case could be `Application.Vlookup`. Then again, `Vlookup` would not be the fastest way on a large data set. In that case you might want to try: `Application.Match`.

Comment: Another possibility is to quickly load columns `G:H` into a dictionary and access these items in your loop. Either way, as you currently go through cells (`Range` objects), your code can also be ran faster going through arrays instead (since you mentioned this will be slow)

Comment: Hi @JvdV and thank you for your help :)!! should i just add this: Cells(erow + 1, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(erow + 1, 8).Value, Range("A2:A10"), 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments you can speed up your process by going through memory instead of `Range` objects (accessing cells one after the other is slow).

So with this specific sample data that looks like:

[image]

Example code could look like:

```
Sub Test()

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Populate dictionary from column G:H
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("G1:H" & lr)
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict.Add arr(x, 1), arr(x, 2)
    Next x

    'Delete duplicates in columns A:E
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:E" & lr).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlNo

    'Go through remaining values to get values for column F
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:F" & lr)
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(x, 6) = dict(arr(x, 1))
    Next x

    'Populate column F
    .Range("A1:F" & lr) = arr

End With

End Sub
```

Would result in:

[image]

---

Comment: Oh wow @JvdV ... you already answered!! I will put my head into this (takes a while) and get back to you soon! :) thank you for helping!!

Comment: Yeah, I put up an answer making use of dictionary instead of `Application.Match` due to the fact it seems not all your values in column A are represented in your lookup table. In that case you would have had to deal with either an extra check or some error handling. Dictionary works very fast though @emppunen

Comment: @emppunen, also feel free to ask questions regarding this code if you not sure what a certain part is doing. Also notice a small edit to write values to the worksheet at once instead of 1 by 1

Comment: i have couple of questions :) If a have title on column F, but when I run the code you made, it deletes it. I tried to change the values that i doesnt delete it, but it still does. Second question is about deleting duplicates. If I want that macro deletes a row only if column A, B and C are the same, how do I change that? I tried to add more values in to array(1, 2, 3) but it gave me an error code.. Thank you again :)

Comment: @emppunen, I have used your sample data without headers, so simple set `Header:=xlNo` back to `Header:=xlYes` and change starting rows of ranges from 1 to 2. About the error, you must make sure that your array of index numbers are actually within the specified range :). You have accepted the answer, does that mean you were able to solve this yourself?

Comment: it still does remove the header.. from column F.. strange.

Comment: One more question @JvdV :) If I want to delete older row, and save the newest one, how can I change this in the code? thank you one more time!! :)

Comment: @emppunen, you'll need to address issues to the range where you work form/paste to, see how I used `A1:F` or other ranges starting from the first row? You can change those to start from `A2:F` etc. About your second question. That will take another different approach than `RemoveDuplicates`. It would be worth a question on it's own =)

Comment: okay thank you! :) is it okay for you if I use the code that you did for asking 'duplicate question'. Because otherwise its perfect for my use :)

Comment: You most definately can, also referce this answer by clicking the share button is fine. But keep in mind, a good question also includes some own research and attempt ;)

Comment: I will do my best :)